# Retrieving the correct file and data for a player

Tags: java, bukkit

I am having some difficulties retrieving data from files. To start with, here is my main method for file creation, which will be triggered (later) when a player logs in to the server.

```
// SettingsManager.java

private File file;
private FileConfiguration config;

// ...

public void createFile(String fileName) {
    file = new File(UnderCovern.getPlugin().getDataFolder(), fileName + ".yml");

    if ( !file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilLogger.exception(e, "[SettingsManager] Could not create new file.");
        }
    }

    config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
}
```

The file is being created normally for each user - in another class -, with their name as the filename as seen here.

```
SettingsManager.get().createFile(player.getName());
```

However, I do not know exactly how I can retrieve the **correct** `.yml` file for a user, and retrieve **data** from it. This code block throws me a `NullPointerException`.

```
public Rank getRank() {
    if (SettingsManager.get().getConfig().get(player.getName()) != null)
        return (Rank) SettingsManager.get().getConfig().get(player.getName() + ".Rank");

    return null;
}
```

Please also note that I am using the Bukkit framework.

Comment: please show which line the null pointer comes up on. but generally once that happens we cant do much without more code so anyone that answers will just saw any object in that line could be null

Comment: Post the __full__ exact stack trace and relevant code in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
public Rank getRank() {
    if (SettingsManager.get().getConfig().get(player.getName()) != null)
        return (Rank) SettingsManager.get().getConfig().get(player.getName() + ".Rank");

    return null;
}
```

Returns null if `if (SettingsManager.get().getConfig().get(player.getName()) != null)` is equal to null. So, the file probably isn't created, or you try to get a not-existing file. Can I maybe see the .getConfig() method?